# Laravel query as well as check for boolean at the same time in same query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have four Models: User, Question, Answer and Upvote. Models satisfy the following constraints:

- **User** can ask **many questions**.
- A **question** has many **answers**
- An **answer** belongs to a single **question**
- An **answer** have many **upvotes** and downvotes as well

**(just like a simple question answer site)**

Here is the query I have written:

```
DB::table('questions')
    ->join('answers', 'answers.question_id', '=', 'questions.id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'answers.user_id')
    ->select('answers.answer_content as answer_content',
             'answers.created_at as created_at',
             'users.name as name',
             'users.id as u_id',
             'users.user_slug as user_slug'
           )
    ->orderBy('answers.created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Upvotes table contains the columns:

```
user_id, answer_id, upvote(booolean 1 or 0)
```

- 1 - upvoted
- 2 - downvoted

**My Answer model**

```
public function upvote()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Upvote', 'answer_id')->where('upvote', 1);
}

public function downvote()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Upvote', 'answer_id')->where('upvote', 0);
}
```

**Upvote model**

```
public function answer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Answer', 'id');
}
```

And it gives me expected results from **three** tables user, questions and answer.

What I want to add in it is whether current logged in user has upvoted the perticular answer or not with it. (like facebook shows already liked on a post with a color). How that could be achived?

(if no one is logged in then there is nothing to check. if user is logged in then i want to just get one more thing which is true or false with every row after joining )

I dont to know how to add this checking logic whether user has upvoted and then get true or false.

Answer (score -1):

Given an `Answer`:

```
$answer = Answer::find(1);
```

You can search with the authenticated user's id like:

```
$user = $answer->upvotes()->where('user_id', auth()->id())->first();

if ($user) {
    // user has voted
} else {
    // user has not voted
}
```

Or another way would be:

```
$upvote = Upvote::where(['answer_id' => $answer->id, 'user_id' => auth()->id()])->first();
```

Comment: hi @btl thanks , i want to get upvote true or false with the query that i have wrtitten in the question, not separetly. i want to get with the questions and answer when i am joining them all . I dont want to get upvote downvote count but true or false for that user who is logged in